# Why does Google Maps say that driving from San Francisco to Seattle via Portland is 30 minutes faster than driving from San Francisco to Seattle?

Tags: usa, driving, oregon, washington-state, google-maps

I read the following ETAs:

- [GMaps: San Francisco to Seattle](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Jose,+California/Seattle,+Washington/@42.3800311,-125.9688068,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x808fcae48af93ff5:0xb99d8c0aca9f717b!2m2!1d-121.8863286!2d37.3382082!1m5!1m1!1s0x5490102c93e83355:0x102565466944d59a!2m2!1d-122.3320708!2d47.6062095!3e0): 13h23min.
- [GMaps: San Francisco to Seattle via Portland, Oregon](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Jose,+California/Portland,+OR/Seattle,+Washington/@42.3881445,-127.1052167,6z/data=!4m20!4m19!1m5!1m1!1s0x808fcae48af93ff5:0xb99d8c0aca9f717b!2m2!1d-121.8863286!2d37.3382082!1m5!1m1!1s0x54950b0b7da97427:0x1c36b9e6f6d18591!2m2!1d-122.6750261!2d45.5051064!1m5!1m1!1s0x5490102c93e83355:0x102565466944d59a!2m2!1d-122.3320708!2d47.6062095!3e0): 12h55min.

Why does Google Maps say that driving from San Francisco to Seattle via Portland is 28 minutes faster than driving from San Francisco to Seattle?

I would have thought that adding a connecting city would increase the estimate time, not decrease it.

---

Screenshots (taken at the same time):

[GMaps: San Francisco to Seattle](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Jose,+California/Seattle,+Washington/@42.3800311,-125.9688068,6z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x808fcae48af93ff5:0xb99d8c0aca9f717b!2m2!1d-121.8863286!2d37.3382082!1m5!1m1!1s0x5490102c93e83355:0x102565466944d59a!2m2!1d-122.3320708!2d47.6062095!3e0) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210818213850/https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Jose,+California/Seattle,+Washington/@42.3800311,-125.9688068,6z/data=%213m1%214b1%214m14%214m13%211m5%211m1%211s0x808fcae48af93ff5:0xb99d8c0aca9f717b%212m2%211d-121.8863286%212d37.3382082%211m5%211m1%211s0x5490102c93e83355:0x102565466944d59a%212m2%211d-122.3320708%212d47.6062095%213e0)): 13h23min:
[image]

[GMaps: San Francisco to Seattle via Portland, Oregon](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/San+Jose,+California/Portland,+OR/Seattle,+Washington/@42.3881445,-127.1052167,6z/data=!4m20!4m19!1m5!1m1!1s0x808fcae48af93ff5:0xb99d8c0aca9f717b!2m2!1d-121.8863286!2d37.3382082!1m5!1m1!1s0x54950b0b7da97427:0x1c36b9e6f6d18591!2m2!1d-122.6750261!2d45.5051064!1m5!1m1!1s0x5490102c93e83355:0x102565466944d59a!2m2!1d-122.3320708!2d47.6062095!3e0) ([mirror](https://archive.ph/goyyq)): 12h55min:
[image]

Comment: If you look at your own screenshots, one reads "the usual traffic", the other one "no traffic". Clearly adding a stop causes it to change its algorithm somewhat. Maybe taking traffic into account is too complicated when there are stops.

Comment: @Relaxed thanks good catch! Didn't expect the addition of the stop to switch it to no traffic.

Comment: Note that your screenshots are reversed

Comment: My organisation has a new online expenses claiming system including for motor mileage. It has an auto calculate option for a journey where you just enter the start and end (UK) post codes. This, we learned,  is linked to Google Maps 'behind the scenes'. Much puzzlement is caused to users when the journey from A to B is given as a different number of miles than the one from B to A.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey this I can understand in case of a path asymmetry due to eg asymmetrical traffic or one-way roads.

Comment: side note: when actually en-route, I find the Waze app tends to be more agile at re-routing during trips, based on live traffic conditions. Just did a DC-Vermont trip with Waze on one device, Google Maps on the other. Waze tended to be more aggressive in finding up-to-the-minute variations that would save time. Given we only had one vehicle going it wasn't like we could follow both choices for an exact comparison. So YMMV, of course.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Cloverleafs and roundabouts-for-motorway-interchanges will account for that.

Comment: Am I the only one noticing that San Jose is not San Francisco?

Comment: @NPSF3000 until now, yes :) good catch!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Unlikely to be cloverleafs - they (almost) [don't exist in the UK](https://www.roads.org.uk/interchanges/cloverleaf). And roundabouts typically add less to the total distance...

Comment: So to summarize the conclusions of the answers, explicitly driving through Portland eliminates all traffic.  I wish driving through Portland really worked that way!

Comment: @NPSF3000 "hey Google, do you know the way to San José?"?

Comment: @psmears what I mean is some of their "super roundabouts" that encircle an entire interchange between large roads.  Going one way through them can be 0.2km, going the other way can be 1.5.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: That's why I said "typically" - there are indeed a few of that size, but the vast majority of roundabouts (even on major interchanges) are much smaller. There just isn't the space!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The primary difference is traffic.

When you ask for the route from San Jose to Seattle, the website displays the "Leave now" option and calculates a real-time prediction based on current traffic (in this case, "the usual traffic" meaning that traffic is roughly around normal levels). You can see this because the numbers are in green; they'd turn orange or red if there was a major delay due to traffic. For such a long drive, this is only so meaningful, as traffic conditions will inevitably change and you'll surely make some stops along the way, but you can adjust the setting and it will display different time estimates (albeit within large ranges like "typically 12 hr - 15 hr 10 min").

But when you ask for directions for a multi-stop trip, it doesn't use real-time traffic information and is displaying the time "without traffic." Note that the numbers are in white (or black using light mode theming) instead of colored. Presumably, it's doing this because it has no idea how long you might stay in Portland and so has no idea even what traffic to estimate for the Portland—Seattle segment (you may be doing it at rush hour or in the middle of the night).

Furthermore, you've asked for directions to "Portland," which Google Maps has decided is a particular point around the I-5/I-405 interchange. As such, it's routed you through the city. If ask for directions to Seattle, you'll pass through Portland, but will stay on I-5, a shorter route that avoids some of the city traffic.

Comment: (+1) In fact, multiple destinations are not available if you chose another setting than "leave now". Changing the time or adding multiple destinations causes it to switch to a simpler algorithm than that used for a request with "leave now" between two points.

Comment: I believe it uses traffic for *now* until *stop 1*?  Also, if you are driving, when you continue to the next destination, it reevaluates the route using current traffic at the time you leave.

Comment: PSA: When you drag (with a mouse) the route to include a 'via' point it will keep including traffic. Super confusing.

Comment: @DavidMulder That is because 'Via' points are _not_ stops. They are "I want to drive past here, but not stop" as far as mapping providers are concerned.

Comment: The accident was that just south of Tacoma may have made a difference (technically that's part of "traffic", but may be worth pointing out). If you take a look at it now San Jose to Seattle shows 12 hrs 44 min.

Answer (score 29):

When you entered the direct route, google maps suggested the route that takes you through Portland by using the highway that seemed most "direct" to Seattle and it made sure to avoid making you "enter" Portland:

[image]

However, when you added Portland as a stop, google maps took the liberty of finding the best route within Portland which resulted in avoiding a nasty traffic in the same "direct" highway that was suggested in the direct route:

[image]

Comment: Also google keeps track of traffic in real time.  Right now I'm seeing 14H6m for the direct route and 13H3m for the indirect route.  Different to the OPs times

Comment: @peter I forgot to switch-on the traffic in the first screenshot, now I changed the first screenshot.

Comment: What's even weirder is that the route google is showing me for the "via portland" route is totally different to your screen grab.  It goes via the downtown section and then loops back across the river before getting back on the 405

Comment: @PeterM somehow I am less worried about the rise of the AI, at least for now.

Comment: :D Just as I thought - some subtle tiny change within one of the cities that's invisible on the zoomed-out map. That can add/subtract some surprising time :D:D:D

Comment: At least in the UK, Google attempts to take account of temporary changes like road works, etc. But the results are often ridiculous, like a 10-mile detour on 30mph urban roads to avoid a 5-minute traffic queue on the direct route..

Comment: Adding a stop in "Portland", without specifying an address, means stopping in the center of Portand. That's why the route has to go through the center.

Comment: If you move the portland stop around, to say the same route as the direct route, you'll find that the "stop in portland" route time doesn't change more than a minute.

Comment: The traffic looks worse on the bypass.  Looks like more of a case of keeping you on the 5 so it doesn't have to give 2-3 additional instructions on road changes.